# Boot2Docker (on Windows) running Mongo with shared folder (This file system is not supported)

Tags: mongodb, docker, boot2docker

I am trying to start a Mongo container using shared folders on Windows using Boot2Docker. When starting using `run -it -v /c/Users/310145787/Desktop/mongo:/data/db mongo` i get a warning message inside the container saying:

`WARNING: This file system is not supported.`

After starting mongo shutsdown immediately.

Any hints or tips on how to solve this?

Comment: I have included in the answer the workaround https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/12590 that you saw in https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/846.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, [according to this gist](https://gist.github.com/sevastos/2fa4c86f01541351efe8) and [Sev (`sevastos`)](https://github.com/sevastos), mongo doesn't support mounted volume through the VirtualBox shared folder:

[See mongoDB Productions Notes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/production-notes/#fsync-on-directories):

> MongoDB requires a filesystem that supports `fsync()` on directories.
>   For example, HGFS and Virtual Box’s shared folders do not support this operation.
>
> the easiest solutions of all and a proper way for data persistance is [**Data Volumes**](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#creating-and-mounting-a-data-volume-container):
>
> Assuming you have a container that has VOLUME ["`/data`"]

```
# Create a data volume
docker create -v /data --name yourData busybox true
# and use
docker run --volumes-from yourData ...
```

---

This isn't always ideal (but the following is for Mac, by [Edward Chu (`chuyik`)](https://github.com/chuyik)):

> I don't think it's a good solution, because the data just moved to another container right?
>   But it still inside the container rather than local system(mac disk).
>
> I found another solution, that is to use sshfs to map data between boot2docker vm and your mac, which may be better since data is not stored inside linux container.
>
> Create a directory to store data inside boot2docker:

```
boot2docker ssh
mkdir -p /mnt/sda1/dev
```

> Use sshfs to link boot2docker and mac:

```
echo tcuser | sshfs docker@localhost:/mnt/sda1/dev <your mac dir path> -p 2022 -o password_stdin
```

> Run image with mongo installed:

```
 docker run -v /mnt/sda1/dev:/data/db <mongodb-image> mongod
```

---

The [corresponding boot2docker issue](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/846) points out to [docker issue 12590 ( Problem with -v shared folders in 1.6 #12590)](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/12590), which points to the work around of **using double-slash**.

> using a double slash seems to work. I checked it locally and it works.

```
docker run -d -v //c/Users/marco/Desktop/data:/data <image name>
```

> it also works with

```
docker run -v /$(pwd):/data
```

Answer (score 0):

As an workaround I just copy from a folder before mongo deamon starts. Also, in my case I don't care of journal files, so i only copy database files.

I've used this command on my docker-compose.yml

`command: bash -c "(rm /data/db/*.lock && cd /prev && cp *.* /data/db) && mongod"`

And everytime before stoping the container I use:

`docker exec <container_name> bash -c 'cd /data/db && cp $(ls *.* | grep -v *.lock) /prev'`

Note: /prev is set as a volume. `path/to/your/prev:/prev`

Another workaround is to use mongodump and mongorestore.

- in docker-compose.yml: `command: bash -c "(sleep 30; mongorestore
  --quiet) & mongod"`
- in terminal: `docker exec  <container_name> mongodump`

Note: I use sleep because I want to make sure that mongo started, and it takes a while.

I know this involves manual work etc, but I am happy that at least I got mongo with existing data running on my Windows 10 machine, and still can work on my Macbook when I want.

Answer (score -3):

It's seems like you don't need the data directory for MongoDb, removing those lines from your docker-composer.yml should run without problems.

The data directory is only used by mongo for cache.