# Docker cannot start MongoDb with attached volume through data-only container

Tags: mongodb, docker, storage, docker-compose

I'm trying to run a `docker-compose` on my **Windows** machine spinning up a **MongoDB** instance and a *data-only* container which proxies an attached *volume* containing the database files.

```
mongodata:  
  image: mongo:2.6.8
  volumes:
    - ./data/db:/data/db
  command: --break-mongo
mongo:  
  image: mongo:2.6.8
  volumes_from:
    - mongodata
  ports:
    - "27017:27017"
  command: --smallfiles --rest
```

*p.s. the --break-mongo command is there on purpose as it just needs to create the volume

To my understanding, using a `data-only` volume pattern would handle permission issues but I can see the following error during the Mongo container startup:

```
 [0m2016-01-26T00:23:52.340+0000 [initandlisten] info preallocateIsFaster couldn't run due to: couldn't open file /data/db/journal/tempLatencyTest for writing errno:1 Operation not permitted; returning false
 [0m2016-01-26T00:23:52.341+0000 [initandlisten] Unable to remove temporary file due to: boost::filesystem::remove: Text file busy: "/data/db/journal/tempLatencyTest"
 [0m2016-01-26T00:23:52.344+0000 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 13516 couldn't open file /data/db/journal/j._0 for writing errno:1 Operation not permitted, terminating
```

**Therefore I'm unable to use MongoDb with an attached volume from my local machine. Is there any way around this issue?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockervolumes/) states

> If you are using Docker Machine on Mac or Windows, your Docker daemon
>   has only limited access to your OS X or Windows filesystem. Docker
>   Machine tries to auto-share your /Users (OS X) or C:\Users (Windows)
>   directory. So, you can mount files or directories on OS X using.
>
> `docker run -v /Users/<path>:/<container path> ...`
>
> On Windows, mount directories using:
>
> `docker run -v /c/Users/<path>:/<container path> ...`
>
> All other paths come from your virtual machine’s filesystem. For example, if you are
>   using VirtualBox some other folder available for sharing, you need to
>   do additional work. **In the case of VirtualBox you need to make the
>   host folder available as a shared folder in VirtualBox**. Then, you can
>   mount it using the Docker -v flag.

Basically, either try to give a full path beginning from your `C:\Users` folder as shown above, or if you can't have that, make the host folder a shared folder in Virtualbox.

**Update**

No need to give a full path. `docker-compose` will handle that. You have to make sure that your `docker-compose.yml` is inside (somewhere down the line) of your `Users` folder. It can't be in some root folder. If you are already doing that, then you will have to adjust your permissions. Just give full permissions to that folder.

Comment: The `data` directory is directly under my `c:\users` directory. I'm not really sure as to where I should set the permissions. To my understanding the "data-only" volume `mongodata` should give full permissions to the `/data/db` path from the `mongo` container? If not, how do I know what `UID`/`GID` to use for permissions?

Comment: I'm accepting it for the lack of a better answer. But I still can't run Mongo with attached volumes...

Answer (score 0):

**Update: Check out the [latest Docker for Windows and MacOS X](https://blog.docker.com/2016/03/docker-for-mac-windows-beta/).**

> Faster and more reliable: no more VirtualBox! The Docker engine is
>   running in an Alpine Linux distribution on top of an xhyve Virtual
>   Machine on Mac OS X or on a Hyper-V VM on Windows, and that VM is
>   managed by the Docker application. You don’t need docker-machine to
>   run Docker for Mac and Windows.

Note: if Windows, you need Windows 10 Pro to make it work as Hyper-V is not included in other releases.

For Docker Toolbox previously, it seems there is no solution at all on Windows and OS X due to VirtualBox. The image documentation indeed [states](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/):

> WARNING (Windows & OS X): The default Docker setup on Windows and OS X
>   uses a VirtualBox VM to host the Docker daemon. Unfortunately, the
>   mechanism VirtualBox uses to share folders between the host system and
>   the Docker container is not compatible with the memory mapped files
>   used by MongoDB (see [vbox bug](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/819), [docs.mongodb.org](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/production-notes/#fsync-on-directories) and related
>   [jira.mongodb.org](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8600) bug). This means that it is not possible to run a
>   MongoDB container with the data directory mapped to the host

Comment: re mongo mounting data/db - still doesn't work with that setup (Windows 10 and Hyper-V) :(.

Answer (score 0):

As an workaround I just copy from a folder before mongo deamon starts. Also, in my case I don't care of journal files, so i only copy database files.

I've used this command on my docker-compose.yml

`command: bash -c "(rm /data/db/*.lock && cd /prev && cp *.* /data/db) && mongod"`

And everytime before stoping the container I use:

`docker exec <container_name> bash -c 'cd /data/db && cp $(ls *.* | grep -v *.lock) /prev'`

Note: /prev is set as a volume. `path/to/your/prev:/prev`

Another workaround is to use mongodump and mongorestore.

- in docker-compose.yml: `command: bash -c "(sleep 30; mongorestore
  --quiet) & mongod"`
- in terminal: `docker exec  <container_name> mongodump`

Note: I use sleep because I want to make sure that mongo started, and it takes a while.

I know this involves manual work etc, but I am happy that at least I got mongo with existing data running on my Windows 10 machine, and still can work on my Macbook when I want.

(croscopy https://stackoverflow.com/a/42044756/1894856)